# Including completed projects in my website (portfolio)

Tags: freelance-websites, consulting, portfolio

### Background

I am an AI consultant and I work developing custom algorithms to solve problems for clients.

I would to put, on my website, the list of clients I had and a summary page for the past projects, to promote my work.

### Question

- Is it considered bad practice or less credible to include projects without mentioning for whom I did them?
- To mention a client (with logo) on my website (e.g. saying I did some project for them), is it necessary to have their written consent?

Comment: I once mentioned clients on my website. A prospect contacted some of them and as they were large, the person the prospect contacted had never heard of me. Since then, I don't mention client names.

Answer (score 1):

For my portfolio site, I would usually include screenshots directly showing the work I did. This was also built into my contract with my clients (I am allowed to create a screenshot and share it to show off my completed work).

Depending on what you're after, this may suffice. I tend to NOT include the company names directly, unless they're asking for it (so far, hasn't). This would help with @DavidR's comment above if dealing with a larger company who doesn't know everyone who touched a project.